# ${folder} in Netbeans templates?

Tags: php, templates, netbeans

In Netbeans templates, there are the variables ${name} and ${nameAndExt} to get the filename automatically into the file's initial setup.

Is there a way to also include the file's location relative to the base directory? I know there's ${package}, but that produces errors when used with PHP templates (and probably wouldn't act as expected even if it didn't).